# Accomplish an "add file" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to accomplish an `add file` button in a sidebar of a normal editor. Precisely,

1. there is a `+` button. After clicking on it, an input field is displayed at the place.
2. the user types the name of the new file, then press `enter` on the keyboard to submit
3. the name of the new file is displayed, and a new `+` button is appended below it.

I have written the following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/luhedimula/1/edit?html,output)). It does not work well: I don't know why `enter` on the keyboard does not submit; and of cause the 3rd point is not accomplished.

Could anyone help me amend the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    li { list-style-type: none }
    .add-file { cursor: pointer }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> file 1</li>
    <li> <div class="add-file">+</div>
  </ul>
  <script>
    $('.add-file').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.add-file').html('<form action=""><input type="text" name="filename"><input type="submit" style="display:none"></form>');
      $('.add-file').removeClass('add-file');
      $("form").submit(function (event) {
        alert($("input:first").val())
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally put the event listener on the text input. You can then pass the event, listen for `event.which` of 13 (enter button) and then do what you need to do with the value of the input.

JSFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/z6c61sbw/

```
$('.add-file').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.add-file').html('<form action=""><input type="text" name="filename"><input type="submit" style="display:none"></form>');
  $('.add-file').removeClass('add-file');

  // Handle the dynamic DOM addition of text input
  $(document).on('keyup', 'input[name="filename"]', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (e.which === 13) {
      alert(this.value);
      // Now you can submit the form...
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you... but how could I "submit the form" manually inside the listener?

Comment: I updated the fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/z6c61sbw/1/ Basically you can call `$('form').submit();`, although, I would recommend giving it a unique ID in the chance there are other forms on the page.

Comment: I'm guessing though that because of the dynamic nature of your page, you'd rather POST the data via AJAX? If that's the case, you can use the `$.ajax()` jQuery method, serialize the form data using `$('form').serialize()`, and then POSTing that data to your service. I'm adding this comment as a guess to what you're trying to accomplish though. Good luck!